# Clear all contents of form with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Is there a method to clear all form elements of a form using JQuery?

Say I have a form like below:

```
<form id="myForm">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"/> <br/>
    Message: <input type="text" name="message"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form"/>
</form>
```

I could do something like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //ajax call here
    }).done(function() {
        $('input[name="name"]').val("");
        $('input[name="message"]').val("");
    });
});
```

This method clears each form element, but is there a broader method that just clears content of an entire form? Some pseudo like `$('#myForm').clearInputs();`? If just so it's easier/shorter to clear all elements at once than clear element 1, clear element 2, ...

Comment: Do you want to clear them or reset them to their initial value, like when the user clicks on the `Reset` button?

Comment: @Barmar, clear them of all text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another way that catches radios and checkboxes as well.

```
$('#myForm').find(':input').each(function() {
    switch (this.type) {
        case 'password':
        case 'select-multiple':
        case 'select-one':
        case 'text':
        case 'textarea':
            $(this).val('');
            break;
        case 'checkbox':
        case 'radio':
            this.checked = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is really the best way to do it. You can't just reset inputs like others have shown, you need to reset the checkbox's and radio buttons.

Comment: I don't see any difference than calling the reset method on the form, except reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @chromano, what if a form element has a value attribute? `.reset()` will return all form form elements to their initial values, whereas clearing them will remove any text or `:checked` from form elements instead of reverting back.

Comment: @gator I see, I didn't pay attention to this requirement, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

My first answer was to give all your inputs, textareas, radios and checkboxes a unique class like `.clear-after` and then you only need one line of JS:

```
$('.clear-after').val('');
```

But after looking it up, there is some vanilla JS that will do this:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

or

```
$("#myForm").reset();
```

Comment: +1 for reset. My next question would have been how to reset form contents to initial values, this does the trick. Cheers!

Comment: $("#myForm").reset() doesn't work, you need to use: $("#myForm")[0].reset()

Answer (score 1):

This will run `val("")` on ALL the form's text input fields:

```
$('#myForm input[type="text"]').val("");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single selector to apply a function to all the inputs in the form:

```
$('#myForm input').val("");
```